# python - atom IDE how to enable auto-complete code to see all functions from a module

Tags: python, autocomplete, ide, atom-editor

I am using atom IDE for my python projects.
there are auto-complete suggestions in some cases but I'd like to know if it's possible to have a list of all possible functions that a imported module has, for instance if i import 
`import urllib`
when I type `urlib.` and press (ctrl+tab) would like to see a list with the possible functions/methods to use.

Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I found the solution for my own question.
Actually I had the wrong plugin installed!

So, in the IDE, edit->preferences, and in the packages section just typed *autocomplete-python* and press install button.

After restart Atom, it should start work :)

Comment: I know its been a while since this thread were active, but... could you tell me how you get `autocomplete-python` to work with python3? (instead of the default python 2)

Comment: I belive it's the same, you might have to change your python executable path. Check also the Settings, there are more options you can configure.

Answer (score 5):

Atom is getting various modifications. Autocomplete-python package is a handy package which helps code faster. The way to install it has changed.
In all new Atom editor go to File->Settings->install
search for `autocomplete-python`
and click on install. Voila its done, restart Atom is not required and you will see the difference with next time you edit python code.

Deb

Answer (score 0):

Atom have a built-in package called [autocomplete-plus](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus). You can extends its functionalities by installing [autocomplete-plus-python-jedi](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus-python-jedi).

from Atom page:

> ### Description:
>
> This is a provider for the awesome Autocomplete Plus making it ready for Python code.
>
> ### Features
>
> - Autocompletion from Jedi.
> - Suggestions include functions' methods (optionally) - just tab through them!
> - Comes with bundled Jedi - no need for jedi in your pythonpath
>
> ### Installation
>
> Either use Atoms package manager or `apm install autocomplete-plus-python-jedi`